# Showing that $\frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|}=0, \text{ as $x \to 0$}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be differentiable at $x=0.$ Show that $$\frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|}=0, \text{ as $x \to 0$}$$ if and only if $f(0) = 0$ and $Df(0) = 0.$

Using the definition $f(x)-f(a) = Df(a)(x-a)+\|x-a\|\varepsilon(x-a)$ I get that

$$f(x)-0=0+\|x-0\|\varepsilon(x-0) \Rightarrow f(x) = \|x\|\varepsilon(x).$$

Dividing by $\|x\|$ I have that $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|}=\varepsilon(x)$. Now doesn't $\varepsilon(x) \to 0$ by definition? Thus $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} \to 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The reverse implication is by definition of the derivative.

Regarding the direct implication, we have $f(0) = 0$ and $Df(0)$ as $f$ is supposed to be differentiable at $0$ and by uniqueness of the limit and derivative at a  point.